# Debian doesn't recognize touchpad

Tags: touchpad

I have installed Debian testing on a laptop Packard Bell EasyNote ENTF71BM. I using LXDE.

I can't configure the touchpad because Debian doesn't recognize it. I installed `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`, and uninstalled the package `synaptics` because it was not working. I had Jessie, but upgrade to testing because don't recognize neither, and package `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` is not in Jessie.

After upgrade and installing `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`:

```
egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps' /proc/bus/input/devices...
```

Nothing!

```
dmesg | grep -i touch ...
```

Nothing!

```
lsmod  | grep -i libinput ...
```

Nothing!

In `xinput` there is no touchpad.

Can someone help?

Comment: Read carefully through `dmesg` directly after boot, and see if there's anything that looks like your touchpad. Grepping for terms like "touch" won't help if you don't know how it'll show up. If you've trouble interepreting the `dmesg` output, put it into a pastebin etc., and post a link.